# Get the mouse coordinates in Firefox 18, IE 9, Chrome 24

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I try to obtain the mouse coordinates, for an event (for example document.onmousemove), but, i get different values for IE9. I use this function.

```
function mouseCoords(event){
if(event.pageX || event.pageY){
    return {x:event.pageX, y:evevent.pageY};
}
return { //IE
    x:event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
    y:event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
};}
```

¿Exists a solution for these three browsers?

Comment: `evevent`? and for scroll position, look at what is written [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.scrollY#Notes)

Comment: It's always risky to say that on SO, but the solution to your cross-browser problem is called jQuery :) It has a really nice event object abstraction that handles all cross-browser issues. It should be an answer, but they see jQuery, they hatin'

Answer (score 0):

try this event.client.pageX

```
function mouseCoords(event){
if(event.client.pageX || event.client.pageY){
    return {x:event.client.pageX, y:evevent.client.pageY};
}
return { //IE
    x:evevent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
    y:evevent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
};}
```